# Synaptics touchpad driver issue on Acer Aspire 5755G

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptic, synaptics

From last system upgrade my synaptics touchpad driver's stopped working properly.
The pointer is still working but other options like edge-scroll stopped working since last upgrade.

I tried to reinstall them but nothing changed.
I read ALL old discussions in this and in other forums, but nothing worked to me.
This is the error:

```
synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

here some log and settings infos:

```
grep synapt -i </var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    22.843] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
[    22.843] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    22.843] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    22.843] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    22.843] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    22.843] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x1
[    22.843] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    22.843] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found relative axes
[    22.843] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found x and y relative axes
[    22.843] (II) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Configuring as mouse
[    22.843] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    22.843] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    22.843] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    22.843] (II) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: initialized for relative axes.
[    22.844] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    22.844] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    22.844] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    22.844] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    22.844] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

And:

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                     id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 1.3M HD WebCam                              id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                            id=14    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And:

```
xinput --list-props 13
Device 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (159):    1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (161):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (282):    0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (283):    1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (284):    1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (285):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (278):    2, 1
    Device Node (279):    "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (286):    0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (288):    0
    Axis Labels (289):    "Rel X" (169), "Rel Y" (170)
    Button Labels (290):    "Button Left" (162), "Button Middle" (163), "Button Right" (164), "Button Wheel Up" (165), "Button Wheel Down" (166)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (291):    0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (292):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (293):    50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (295):    1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (296):    3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (297):    20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (298):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (299):    0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (300):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (301):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (302):    4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (303):    0
```

And:

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf 
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

I've a Acer Aspire 5755G laptop.

How can i fix the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by editing your question and explaining exactly what you mean by "stoppet to work properly". Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "stopped" not "stoppet", my fault xD
However with "stopped work properly" I mean that it can't load synaptics driver: pointer is still working but other options like edge-scroll stopped to work since last upgrade.
When I digit into TTY "synclient" the result is: "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"
He worked before last upgrade. Why? What canged?